# Do women naturally form groups to defend themselves?

Tags: gender

[What I'm describing is also further explained in this post, written by and for women apparently.](https://www.jaxmomsblog.com/home-lifestyle/friendship/toughen-up-ladies-criticism-is-not-a-personal-attack/)

Can this behaviour be attributed to the whole gender? Is it a social construct or the outcome of biological differences? And can we generalise about men's behaviour towards criticism?

update:

[this article is a great starting point](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/articles/201711/the-truth-about-sex-differences)

David P Schmitt:

> A d value of +0.50 is considered "moderate" and indicates that 69 percent of men are higher than the average woman on a particular attribute. Sex differences in spatial rotation skills, certain mathematics abilities (3-dimensional geometry and calculus), and **task-oriented leadership (focusing on accomplishing a group goal rather than maintaining harmony within the group) reside within this size range.**

[Due to the anthropological nature of this question, I also asked a related question in Biology.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/80925/are-there-any-social-behavioural-differences-between-the-biological-sexes-in-hum)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  Have you looked for any more information on this?  If so what have you found?  I am not convinced the article you linked is generalising women, but stating an observation about a large number of women.  I don't think you can **or even should** generalise about men or women in any way as everyone is different.

Comment: Well if you believe in evolution and knowing that men and women have performed different tasks and have been part of social processes from different positions, it's not such a weird question. Evolution shaped our bodies and minds and might as well have shaped the collective behaviour I'm talking about. Maybe I should ask this question in anthropology.